# why wont "||" (or) work in my javascript function?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, operators

I  am trying to write the code so that if if given 2 numbers that represent my birthday (month = 11, day = 3) it would log "how did you know". anything else would return "Just Another Day". Also need the order of month and day to not matter.

I  have written it as:

```
function birthday (month,day){
  let result;
  if( month == "11" && day == "3") || (day == "3" && month = "11"){
      result = "How did you know?";
     }
      else {
       result = "Just Another Day";
      }
  return result;
}

console.log(birthday(3, 11));
```

but it returns and tell me the || (or) is an unexpected token...How else could I  write this?

Answer (score 1):

You have two conditions on the two sides of the `||` operator that say the exact same thing. On the second condition, you need to check if the **day** is 11 and the **month** 3. Additionally, you have `=` operator on the last comparison instead of a `==`:

```
if ((month == "11" && day == "3") || (month == "3" && day == "11")) {
```

Comment: @Berto99 yup, good catch. Thanks. Edited and fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You should add "(" after if and add ")" after `(day == "3" && month == "11")`.Also change = operator on the last comparison to == and change last comparison from `(day == "3" && month == "11")` to `(month == "3" && day == "11")`. Change your code to this code:

```js
function birthday (month,day){
      let result;
      if( (month == "11" && day == "3") || (month == "3" && day == "11")){
          result = "How did you know?";
         }
          else {
           result = "Just Another Day";
          }
      return result;
    }
    
    console.log(birthday(3, 11));
```

Answer (score 0):

I modify your code, the last comparison symbol (==) was wrong, it was an asignment symbol(=) and you are comparing day and month twice, now your code works fine!

```js
function birthday (month, day){
  let result = "";

  if(( month == "11" && day == "3") || (month == "3" && day == "11")){
      result = "How did you know?";
     }
      else {
       result = "Just Another Day";
      }
  return result;
}

console.log(birthday(3, 11));
```